# В ИЕ7 мешается бэкграунд

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

```
background: url(/img/dashed.png) 0 6px no-repeat;
```

Есть тире, которое уползает вверх только в ие7, когда больше 2, 3 строчек текста. Как это исправить?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мало информации дали. Что это за элементы? Какие еще стили, кроме background, к ним применены? [Посмотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/dqETJ/) в разных браузерах. Погрешность естественно есть, но не такая значительная, как у вас.

А вообще, коррекировать стили под IE - обычная практика. Через условный комментарий подключаете отдельный файл со стилями, которые будут распространяться только на осла определённых версий.

```
// Подключаете файл стилией для IE ниже восьмой версии
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <link href= "ie7.css" rel= "stylesheet" media= "all" /> <![endif]-->
// В ie7.css
element {
    background:  url(http://path/img.png) 0 15px no-repeat !important;
}
```

Comment: У меня li не был, блочным элементом. Поэтому он и прыгал. У меня сложное меню, так что пришлось изменить. Спасибо